# Proving a certain primitive recursive function exists

Tags: computability, logic, primitive-recursion

Assume $f\colon ω × ω → ω$ is a computable function. How can we prove that there is a primitive recursive function $g\colon ω × ω → ω$ where the following holds:

$∀n [∃s(f(n, s) = 1) ↔ ∃k(g(n, k) = 1)]$

So for every $n$, there is an $s$ such that $f(n, s) = 1$ if and only if there is a $k$ such that $g(n, k) = 1$.

Been working on this problem for a while now, if anyone could please help?

Answer (score 1):

The function $g$ interprets $k$ as two inputs $k_1,k_2$. It runs $f(n,k_1)$ for $k_2$ steps, returns whatever $f$ does if $f$ halts, and returns $0$ otherwise.